# How to get a Dynamic Control Type based on the AttributeID Field

Tags: c#, acumatica

For Example, If I Select `AttributeID` as a `COLOR` and it has Control Type `Combo` then the `Default Value` field changes to `Drop Down`. If I Select `AttributeID` as `CONFIGURAB` and it has Control Type `Text` then the `Default Value` changes to `Text`.

Please check the below Images (Combo, Text)

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSGmV.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7wH6.png)

I created a `New Screen` and tried to get the same thing in the `Attribute` Tab.
 The `Default Value` field is not changing dynamically based on the `AttributeID` selection

Below are the DAC Fields that I used in My New Screen

```
 #region AttributeID
        public abstract class attributeID : PX.Data.IBqlField
        {
        }
        protected string _AttributeID;
        [PXDBString(10, IsUnicode = true, IsKey = true, InputMask = ">aaaaaaaaaa")]       
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Attribute ID", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
        [PXSelector(typeof(CSAttribute.attributeID))]
        public virtual string AttributeID
        {
            get
            {
                return this._AttributeID;
            }
            set
            {
                this._AttributeID = value;
            }
        }
        #endregion
    #region DefaultValue
        public abstract class defaultValue : PX.Data.IBqlField
        {
        }
        protected string _DefaultValue;
        [PXDBString(255, IsUnicode = true)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Default Value")]
        [DynamicValueValidation(typeof(Search<CSAttribute.regExp, Where<CSAttribute.attributeID, Equal<Current<TSOrderTypeAttribute.attributeID>>>>))]
        public virtual string DefaultValue
        {
            get
            {
                return this._DefaultValue;
            }
            set
            {
                this._DefaultValue = value;
            }
        }
        #endregion
```

Answer (score 0):

Appears that you are trying to extend Attribute support to your new custom entity. If so, please refer this [KB article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51867197/how-to-add-attribute-support-to-out-of-box-sales-order-entity/51867198#51867198).