# How to add Attribute Support to out-of-box Sales Order Entity?

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

Out-of-box `Acumatica Sales Order (SO301000)` does not have attribute support. How to extend attribute support to Sales Order entity in Acumatica?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the very core, your entity main DAC must have GUID column (`NoteID`) to reference `CSAnswers` table and must have field that identify the class of the Entity.

We will make use of `Order Type` to define list of attributes to gather particular order type-specific information.

Create a Graph Extension for `SOOrderTypeMaint` Graph and declare data view to define list of attributes for a particular order type. We will be using out-of-box `CSAttributeGroupList<TEntityClass, TEntity>`

```cs
public class SOOrderTypeMaintPXExt : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderTypeMaint>
{
    [PXViewName(PX.Objects.CR.Messages.Attributes)]
    public CSAttributeGroupList<SOOrderType, SOOrder> Mapping;
}
```

Create a Graph Extension for `SOOrderEntry` Graph and declare data view for attributes specific to current order type.

```cs
public class SOOrderEntryPXExt : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
{
    public CRAttributeList<SOOrder> Answers;
}
```

Create DAC Extension for `SOOrder` DAC and declare user defined field decorated with `CRAttributesField` attribute and specify the `ClassID` field – in our case it is `OrderType`.

```cs
public class SOOrderPXExt : PXCacheExtension<SOOrder>
{
    #region UsrAttributes

    public abstract class usrAttributes : IBqlField { }

    [CRAttributesField(typeof(SOOrder.orderType))]
    public virtual string[] UsrAttributes { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

Modify Order Types page (`SO201000`) as below using Customization Engine

```aspx
<px:PXTabItem Text = "Attributes" >
  <Template>
    <px:PXGrid runat = "server" BorderWidth="0px" Height="150px" SkinID="Details" Width="100%" ID="AttributesGrid" 
                MatrixMode="True" DataSourceID="ds">
        <AutoSize Enabled = "True" Container="Window" MinHeight="150" />
        <Levels>
            <px:PXGridLevel DataMember = "Mapping" >
                <RowTemplate>
                    <px:PXSelector runat = "server" DataField="AttributeID" FilterByAllFields="True" AllowEdit="True" 
                                    CommitChanges="True" ID="edAttributeID" /></RowTemplate>
                <Columns>
                    <px:PXGridColumn DataField = "AttributeID" Width="81px" AutoCallBack="True" LinkCommand="ShowDetails" />
                    <px:PXGridColumn DataField = "Description" Width="351px" AllowNull="False" />
                    <px:PXGridColumn DataField = "SortOrder" TextAlign="Right" Width="81px" />
                    <px:PXGridColumn DataField = "Required" Type="CheckBox" TextAlign="Center" AllowNull="False" />
                    <px:PXGridColumn DataField = "CSAttribute__IsInternal" Type="CheckBox" TextAlign="Center" AllowNull="True" />
                    <px:PXGridColumn DataField = "ControlType" Type="DropDownList" Width="81px" AllowNull="False" />
                    <px:PXGridColumn DataField = "DefaultValue" RenderEditorText="False" Width="100px" AllowNull="True" />
                </Columns>
            </px:PXGridLevel>
        </Levels>
    </px:PXGrid>
  </Template>
</px:PXTabItem>
```

Modify Sales Orders page (`SO301000`) as below using Customization Engine

```aspx
<px:PXTabItem Text="Attributes">
  <Template>
    <px:PXGrid runat="server" ID="PXGridAnswers" Height="200px" SkinID="Inquire" 
                Width="100%" MatrixMode="True" DataSourceID="ds">
        <AutoSize Enabled="True" MinHeight="200" />
        <ActionBar>
            <Actions>
                <Search Enabled="False" />
            </Actions>
        </ActionBar>
        <Mode AllowAddNew="False" AllowDelete="False" AllowColMoving="False" />
        <Levels>
            <px:PXGridLevel DataMember="Answers">                        
                <Columns>
                    <px:PXGridColumn TextAlign="Left" DataField="AttributeID" TextField="AttributeID_description" 
                                        Width="250px" AllowShowHide="False" />
                    <px:PXGridColumn Type="CheckBox" TextAlign="Center" DataField="isRequired" Width="80px" />
                    <px:PXGridColumn DataField="Value" Width="300px" AllowSort="False" AllowShowHide="False" />
                </Columns>
            </px:PXGridLevel>
        </Levels>
    </px:PXGrid>
  </Template>
</px:PXTabItem>
```

[Download deployment package](https://github.com/Acumatica/PXSOAttributeSupportExtPkg/)